# Как организовать проект c#, содержащий несколько unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

У меня довольно странная ситуация.
Есть три USB устройства, которые поставляются с x86 и x64 dll.

Делают они одну и ту же работу, но для каждого скомпилирована "своя" dll, которая экспортирует функцию с некоторым именем, в зависимости от устройства.
Сигнатура функции одинакова, но параметры разные, в зависимости от устройства.

Как организовать проект в Visual Studio таким образом, чтобы было удобнее всего с этим работать?

Насколько я понимаю, мне нужен для этих устройств "свой маленький DirectX", если можно так выразиться.

Я примерно понимаю, как сделать такую обертку, но как сделать так, чтобы в выходную папку копировалась нужная из шести dll?

Comment: Я сигнатура функции формируется на базе параметров, она не может быть одинаковой для ф-ций с разными параметрами.

Comment: Проблема с чем именно? С рефлексией? Проблема для каждого устройства создать "интерфейс"? Проблема скопировать файл?

Comment: В постбуилд степ вам доступны параметры наподобие `$(ConfigurationName)` и `$(PlatformName)`.

Comment: @nick_n_a, имелись ввиду значения параметров, т.е. для обращения к устройству нужно вызвать функцию, где первым параметром идет код устройства. Как говорится, тут велосипед не мой, за чем так сделано - не знаю. Определить VID/PID подключенного устройства и подгрузить нужную DLL не проблема. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как для каждого устройства в зависимости от разрядности сборки копировать нужную DLL. Создавать 6 Release и 6 Debug конфигураций?

Comment: @VladD, тут, как я понимаю, необходимо ручное редактирование *.csproj?

Comment: @mainefremov: Не обязательно, у вас же есть Postbuild Step

Comment: @VladD, не понимаю, ну "не шмогла я", как сделать так, чтобы в выходную папку в одном случае копировалась одна пара dll, во втором случае - вторая, в третьем - третья. Для каждого пользователя (их 3) есть своё USB устройство, к нему привязана своя пара dll, для каждой пары нужно вызывать функцию с определенным именем и значениями параметров. Пихать это по трем разным солюшенам, это бред, как это потом синхронизировать и поддерживать...

Comment: @mainefremov: А как вы при компиляции узнаёте, что вы вот сейчас компилируете для устройства _X_, а не для устройства _Y_?

Comment: @VladD, в данный момент я вручную кладу нужную пару dll в папку, после чего меняю прямо в коде имя функции и передаваемые ей параметры, т.е. пока что вот такой костыль.

Comment: Ну тогда есть смысл и правда создать N build target'ов.